# Combining Tables In R

Tags: r, merge, cbind

UPDATED

I encountered a problem while trying to perform a simple table merging task in R. I'm looking for why this happened and, if it exists, a more elegant solution. Below is the exact data I'm working with and what happened.

I have two tables from a survey related to how different political parties and business people think about a political issue. They come from two different datasets, which I don't want to merge (for various reasons). Each data has the exact same names for values. But, when I used `cbind` to merge the columns, the rows get reverse for some columns and I can't figure out why.

My data

```
library(survey)
founders.services <- 
structure(c(38, 43, 131, 172, 177, 122, 34, 12, 114, 70, 17, 
27), .Dim = c(2L, 6L), .Dimnames = structure(list(services = c("compete", 
"similar"), party = c("skipped", "Democrat", "Independent", "Libertarian", 
"Republican", "other")), .Names = c("services", "party")))

public.services.party <- 
structure(c(26, 103), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(services = c("similar", 
"compete")), .Names = "services"), class = c("svytable", "xtabs", 
"table"), call = svytable.survey.design(formula = ~services, 
    design = fss))
```

And, how I combine them:

```
cbind(founders.services, public.services.party)
```

In the first (and correct) table, under the column "libertarian", the row "compete" has the value of 34 and "similar" has 12. But, in the combined table (with cbind), it's the reverse. If the names were different, they should show up as different columns. But, cbind seems to recognize that they are both the same values.

Why is this happening?

And, more generally, if there's a better way to combine tables, I'm happy to consider alternatives. Basically what I have is a few different data sets where various populations (political party, business type) answered the same questions. I can't merge the datasets, but would like to combine the tables for analysis.

Thanks and please let me know if I can make this question any more clear.

UPDATED: with code and tables.

Here is the correct table

```
services  skipped Democrat Independent Libertarian Republican other
  compete      38      131         177          34        114    17
  similar      43      172         122          12         70    27
```

Here is the combined table with error. you will need the "survey" package to replicate.

```
        founders.services skipped Democrat Independent Libertarian Republican other
similar                26      38      131         177          34        114    17
compete               103      43      172         122          12         70    27
```

Comment: If you're using a package, please toss a `library(my_needed_package)` line into the code.

Comment: You could make it clearer by adding the output that you are getting from cbind, and the output that you expect. In my case, I commented out your svytable function and tried it out, and did not see the behavior you described - I think... not sure because I could be misinterpreting your text.

Comment: ok thanks! @Frank i added that you need the "survey" R package (did I do that right?)

Comment: @Mike Wise. I put in the tables, at least how they're being displayed for me.

Comment: @tom Thanks. I've edited it to show what I meant. The advantage is that the code can now be copy-pasted in so that we're looking at the same objects with the same names as you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is taking the row names from the first data frame you put in the cbind command. If you just reverse the order of the cbind, you will get what you want:

```
> cbind( public.services.party,founders.services)
        skipped Democrat Independent Libertarian Republican other founders.services
compete      38      131         177          34        114    17                26
similar      43      172         122          12         70    27               103
```

You can reorder columns and rows as you wish afterwards.

Comment: That makes sense. As a general note, `rownames` are messy. Found this summary via google: http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/06/16/never-trust-the-row-names-of-a-dataframe-in-R/

Comment: Was wondering how to merge them using the row names, but couldn't think of a way right away, then it occurred to me to try it reversed. My R is a bit rusty, been pythoning and hiving...

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better way to merge tables? sometimes i merge more than 2 tables and i'd like a reliable way to do it, without having to worry about the order.

Comment: Probably not using rownames, see the article from Frank above, they are not reliable. You should use another column as your index, and then use functions like merge to "join" them. Like in SQL.

Comment: You waiting for another answer?

Comment: Perhaps I asked the wrong question, because this is a solution, but it doesn't work for more than two pairs. I need a solution for multiple vectors or lists. Sometimes i'll only have one vector. sometimes it will be a table. the row names (or column) names would be the same, but vectors don't have columns. Hmm....

Comment: You need to use merge to join them. Need to finish something, and then I will post a more general alternative.

Comment: thanks @MikeWise! just to keep in mind, some tables are just a single vector. cbind would lable the column name by the object name. So, not sure how to merge vectors on to tables, when the original output isn't a columns (if that makes sense). thanks again!

Comment: I see you are using matrices and not data.frames. You probably need to take a more data.frame oriented approach, match does not work on  matrices. I got something to work but I had to convert to data.frames first.

Comment: @MikeWise do you mind working that out in another thread or showing us how you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the other way I mentioned, using a function to match on the row numbers. It relies on converting to data frames though, not sure if that is acceptable.

You also need to address the name change of the first column of the resulting data frame.

```
library(survey)
fs <- structure(
                  c(38, 43, 131, 172, 177, 122, 34, 12, 114, 70, 17, 27), 
                 .Dim = c(2L, 6L), 
                 .Dimnames = structure(list(services = c("compete", "similar"), 
                                party = c("skipped", "Democrat", "Independent", 
                                "Libertarian", "Republican", "other")), 
                                   .Names = c("services", "party")))

psp <- structure(c(26, 103), 
                 .Dim = 2L, 
                 .Dimnames = structure(list(services = c("similar", "compete")), 
                                       .Names = "services")
#                  ,class = c("svytable", "xtabs", "table")
#                , call = svytable.survey.design(formula = ~services, 
#                                              design = fss)
                 )
cbind(fs, psp)

cbind( psp,fs)

mergeByRowName <- function(d1,d2){
   d1 <- data.frame(d1)
   d2 <- data.frame(d2)
   d1$rn <- rownames(d1)
   d2$rn <- rownames(d2)
   d3 <- merge(d1,d2,by="rn")
   rownames(d3) <- d3$rn
   d3$rn <- NULL
   return(d3)
}
d3 <- mergeByRowName(fs,psp)
d3
```

Yields this:

```
        skipped Democrat Independent Libertarian Republican other  d2
compete      38      131         177          34        114    17 103
similar      43      172         122          12         70    27  26
```